# POST API calls Suddenly sending Error Messages in iOS Only

Tags: ios, api, post, swift5

I have suddenly started getting error messages in Working REST API calls in which were till yet working fine.

Most importantly it was not an issue with application but all the applications who were handled from the One specific server stopped working.

**Important :**

- Same API Calls still works fine on Android Apps, Even tested on POSTMAN it still works fine, but not on iOS part only
- In iOS Also issue comes into POST API calls only, GET API Calls still works fine

**Error Message :**

> Printing description of error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

**Here is what I have tried so far :**

```
func doSignInAPICall(mEmailMobile: String, mPassword: String, completionhandler: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: mainAPIURL+LoginAPI)! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: timeoutTime)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
    let contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary)
    request.addValue(contentType as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let body = NSMutableData()

    // email_mobile
    body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email_mobile\"\r\n\r\n" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    body.append(NSString(format: mEmailMobile as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

    // password
    body.append(NSString(format: "\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    body.append(NSString(format: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\n" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
    body.append(NSString(format: mPassword as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)

    request.httpBody = body as Data

    constants().APPDEL.doStartSpinner()
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        print(response?.debugDescription)
        if (error != nil) {
            constants().APPDEL.doStopSpinner()
            completionhandler(false)
        } else {
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [.mutableContainers, .fragmentsAllowed]) as? [String: Any] {
                    constants().APPDEL.doStopSpinner()
                    let mDict = (json["response"] as! NSArray).object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary
                    if (mDict.value(forKey: "status") as! String) == "true" {
                        completionhandler(true)
                    } else {
                        completionhandler(false)
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                constants().APPDEL.doStopSpinner()
            }
        }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

**Important Notes :**

- Same APIs Project shifted to some other server & in that case the above code works correctly
- I have confirmed with the Server support team & its verified that it has no SSL or Security level issues & its also HTTPs secure server
- Even my live projects who were running from the same error messages now which are already live on App Store
- In iOS Also issue comes into POST API calls only, GET API Calls still works fine

**EDIT - MORE DETAILS :**

> Optional("\n\n403 Forbidden\n\n
>
> ## Forbidden
>
> \n
>
> You don\'t
>   have permission to access this resource.
>
> \n
>
> Additionally, a 403
>   Forbidden\nerror was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument
>   to handle the request.
>
> \n\n")

Please suggest me some solution for it.

Any suggestions or hints will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the proper HTTPHeaders?

Comment: @javierrivarola yes I did

Comment: @javierrivarola just before 24 hours it was all working fine

Comment: can you try printing the response as string? looks like the error is for the decoding of the response to json

Comment: Yes I already mentioned Error message response string in my question. Please look at it.

Comment: No, i mean the response of the request as string, before trying to decode it with `JSONSerialization.jsonObject..`

Comment: @javierrivarola haven't tried such, can you please suggest me something for decoding

Comment: Create a String from data with utf8 encoding

Comment: Not finding a way to do it

Comment: String(data: yourData, encoding: .utf8)

Comment: if the string you are getting is a valid JSON, then is just a matter of using the correct options with JSONSerialization

Comment: @javierrivarola edited my question with Encoded response

Comment: Ok so you are getting 403 error, that means the server is not allowing you to call that endpoint, are you sure you are using the correct headers for authentication?

Comment: yes as you see I have added correct headers as it requires & it works fine on Postman Calls

Comment: @javierrivarola even I have tried the Code generated from Postman Server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206662/discussion-between-mayur-and-javier-rivarola).

Comment: MYbe you have resolve it but recommend  use proxyman and disable ssl check to check for send request and the response it may give you a clue about what’s wrong with the request